# Can't find database container: Laravel development in local docker containers on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am taking my first steps with Laravel(+passport) using [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-secure-api-php-laravel-passport). I have set up Docker for Win10 using WSL2 and followed the steps using Laravel-Sail to manage the containers (from inside an Ubuntu wsl instance). This runs a separate MySQL container. After several issues getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when running `php artisan migrate:install` I found that I should change `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` in `.env`. Additionally, since I already had a MySQL service running as part of WAMP, I exposed the MySQL container for Sail on port 3366 by adding `FORWARD_DB_PORT=3366` to `.env` and added `'port' => env('FORWARD_DB_PORT', '3306'),` to `config/database.php`. Now I was finally able to work through the tutorial.

Once I got everything up, I tried to test the routes using postman, but at this point, it turns out now the webserver can't find the mysql server. After trying a few things, I figured out that returning the above changes to default fixed this problem. However, now again artisan cannot find the mysql server. I seems like I need to toggle between the two settings to be able to both let the webserver use the mysql server and make changes to it using artisan.

My hunch is that I am trying something that I shouldn't be trying but I cannot figure out what it is I **should** be doing.

The question seems quite simple to me: How to work on a containerized Laravel project locally on Windows10? Or am I making this myself to difficult and should I just use Linux (I personally don't have a problem with this but I should be able to convince my colleagues who are expected to use the same local dev setup)?

Comment: Do you want to run PHP and Mysql in Docker containers (I think it's a better solution) or PHP in Docker and Mysql server on your machine?

Comment: you can use docker-compose to set up your project infrastructure (PHP, Mysql, Nginx) and your containers will see each other

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov I am running PHP and MySQL each in their own container. As I wrote in the question, they do indeed see each other with the default setup, however, Artisan can't find MySQL when I am running it from outside the containers with these defaults. I have now used a janky hack to get it to work. Should I be running artisan from inside the PHP container?

Comment: To run artisan inside the container login into the php container: `docker exec -ti {your_container_name} bash`. To find the container name run in the terminal `docker ps`. Once you are logged in the container you can execute console scripts, including artisan

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov Thanks, that does indeed work. My question is more about whether this is the way it's supposed to work? Since my team and I plan to be working a lot with this setup, we don't want to run into quirks of a janky, non-standard setup for which we can find no solutions in public resources like SO.

Comment: By the way, you can skip that extra step of logging in the container by using a single command: `docker exec -ti {container_name} artisan {your_command}`

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone finding this question having the same trouble as I have: I have found the solution.

As @MichaelKrutikov mentioned in the comments, you should indeed execute the artisan commands inside of the applications container. However, instead of working directly in a shell in the container, the way you are supposed to do this is by running

```
$ ./sail artisan list
```

or `vendor/bin/sail artisan list` in my case. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#laravel-sail).

Somehow, this quite important detail wasn't mentioned in any tutorial or part of any answer to questions that are likely related to this.

Comment: you may refer my tutorial https://dogcomp.medium.com/kickstart-your-laravel-web-app-using-laravel-sail-30276265e588